# Why does my MCreate Java Minecraft mod not compile?

Tags: java, minecraft

Whenever I try to run the mod, it tells me there's something wrong with the mod elements (The weapons and armor in particular), and that they do not compile correctly. This is the line of code it says was wrong (I didn't write it). `new ItemStack(, (int)(1))` It says the comma is illegal. Please help me.

Comment: As the error message says, that's not legal Java.  You could write `new ItemStack(something, something)` or `new ItemStack(something)`, but not `new ItemStack( , something)`.  See the difference?

Comment: Right, the extra comma in the beginning is the problem.  Lose it.

Comment: Also the construction `(int)(1)` is kinda weird.  Just use `1` it's the same thing.

Comment: None of these seem to help. Thanks for trying, though.

Comment: HI @JavaTheHutt - have you looked at the Javadoc for _ItemStack_ - it has quite a few variants but the first parameter needs to be an _Item_ or a _Block_  .. maybe it will allow null for that parameter - you can put null and it'll compile, but unfortunately that's not documented what the runtime will do if you do that.  Also you want be able to do `ItemStack(null, 1);` because there are 2 versions that it could match - you'll need to do something like `ItemStack((Item)null, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

In Java (such as lot of other languages), this is not a valid syntax.

You should do something like:

```java
new ItemStack(Material.MY_ITEM); // create item with default amount (1)
new ItemStack(Material.MY_ITEM, 2); // create item with 2 as amount
```

Also, you don't need the `(int)` part. You are trying to cast an int as int...